# Delete Old Scheduled Jobs from Batch Class

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I'm having a batch class which gets reschedule after 5 mins and delete old scheduled jobs which has already executed.But i'm unable to delete old jobs and in debug log i'm getting error:"**Exception in deleting job : Only CronTrigger IDs and batch, future, and queueable job IDs are supported.**".Below is the Code I'm using in my finish method :

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
     Datetime dt = system.now().addMinutes(5);

    String day = string.valueOf(dt.day());
    String month = string.valueOf(dt.month());
    String hour = string.valueOf(dt.hour());
    String minute = string.valueOf(dt.minute());
    String second = string.valueOf(dt.second());
    String year = string.valueOf(dt.year());

    String strJobName = 'Send SMS Batch-' + String.valueof(dt);
    String strSchedule = '0 ' + minute + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ?' + ' ' + year;

    if(!test.isRunningTest())
     system.schedule(strJobName, strSchedule, new VGA_ScheduleSendBatchSMS());

    List<CronTrigger> lstCron = [select Id, State, NextFireTime, CronJobDetailId from CronTrigger where NextFireTime = Null AND State = 'DELETED'];

    if(lstCron != Null && !lstCron.isEmpty())
    {
        try
        {
            for(CronTrigger obj : lstCron)  
            {
                system.abortjob(obj.CronJobDetailId);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            system.debug('@@Exception in deleting job : ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: `try-catch`, `if(list != null && !list.isempty())` is all unnecessary.

Comment: Ok.I'll remove the Checks .But are these conflicting with the output i require ?

Comment: I don't see why you're trying to abort aborted jobs, since they're already aborted...

Comment: Yes,But i want them to be removed from list of scheduled jobs as my batch is running every 5 mins and it creates a big list of already executed jobs .so is there any way to remove them from the list of scheduled jobs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To clean up the list, you can purge the old jobs:

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
  System.purgeOldAsyncJobs(Date.today());
```

You should only be calling System.abortJob to cancel jobs that have a future.

In the future, if you do need to abort a CronTrigger, use the Id value, not the CronJobDetailId:

```
for(CronTrigger ct:[SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger]) {
  System.abortJOb(ct.Id);
}
```